# Why am i getting this error? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: "

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point, void, args

Here is the full error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DataEntry/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DataEntry.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Here is my code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class DataEntry {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Frame frm=new Frame("DataEntry frame");
      Label lbl = new Label("Please fill this blank:");
      frm.add(lbl);
      frm.setSize(350,200);
      frm.setVisible(true);
      frm.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
      System.exit(0);
      }
      });
      Panel p = new Panel();
      Panel p1 = new Panel();
      Label jFirstName = new Label("First Name");
      TextField lFirstName = new TextField(20);
      Label jLastName =new Label("Last Name");
      TextField lLastName=new TextField(20);
      p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
      p.add(jFirstName);
      p.add(lFirstName);
      p.add(jLastName);
      p.add(lLastName);
      Button Submit=new Button("Submit");
      p.add(Submit);
      p1.add(p);
     frm.add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
      }
```

}

The file is saved as DataEntry.java and the DataEntry.class file is in the same directory. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code does not matter here. How are you compiling ?

Comment: More specifically, how are you trying to start your class?

Answer (score 5):

When running a Java class, you don't supply the filename of the class, you supply the classname.  If you specify `DataEntry.java`, the interpreter will think you are trying to load the class `java` in the package `DataEntry`, which of course doesn't exist.

Instead of this:

```
java DataEntry.java
```

Do this:

```
java DataEntry
```